syntax highlighting needs rejoining back to common regexes
Is this Vim syntax not capable of rejoining a sequence of regex after a fan-out of choiceing (syntax region) or nextgrouping (syntax match)?  Or is it an issue of following the keyword from a group being called by a parent group, but not other (2) parent groups?
Without resorting to vimscripting, I'll try EBNF to detail this problem.  All group have been renamed for readability (I'm working on the nftables vim syntax and want to spare you the angst of their GNU Bison railroad mnemonics).
Working on syntax highlight, its EBNF are:
Words  ::= ( Statement | Subject )

Subject ::= Fruity_Novel

# Problematic 'Statement'
Statement ::= Fruity_Novel 'has' Outcome
Fruity_Novel ::= ApplePoem | OrangeTale | PearFable

Outcome ::= Cheerful_Ending | Sad_Closure | Delightful_Wrapup

Is this also the case where Vim syntax is forcing us to DUPLICATE the
fruity_novel syntaxes so that it can do both the has <outcome> as well as its <subject>?

Trying a New Approach
such that the new EBNF must be:
fruity_novel            :== <apple-poem> | <orange-tale> | <pear-fable>
fruity_novel_before_has :== <apple-poem> | <orange-tale> | <pear-fable>
outcome :== <cheerful-ending> | <sad-closure> | <delightful-wrapup>

words :== statement | subject

subject :== fruity_novel

statement :== fruity_novel_before_has "has" outcome

Such that the new railroad diagram would be:

So, we cannot reuse the (fruity_novel) subject group again IF BEFORE a keyword without its own duplication (and its own new group name), right?
An attempt at vimscript would be like this:
syn match apple_poem "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words
syn match orange_tale "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words
syn match pear_fable "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words

" The ending flow before going elsewhere "
syn match cheerful_ending "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words
syn match sad_closure "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words
syn match delightful_wrapup "<irrelevant regex>" skipwhite contained
\ nextgroup = words

syn cluster predicate
\ contains=
\    cheerful_ending,
\    sad_closure,
\    delightful_wrapup

syn match verb "has" nextgroup=predicate

" Original subject "
syn match apple_poem "apple_complex_regex"
syn match orange_tale "orange_complex_regex" 
syn match pear_tale "pear_complex_regex" 

" original fruit_novel "
syn cluster fruit_novel_without_has
\ contains
\    apple_poem,
\    orange_tale,
\    pear_fable

" forked out 'fruit_novel' "
" new support for a 'has' statement (same regex as above) "
syn match has_apple_poem "apple_complex_regex" nextgroup=verb
syn match has_orange_tale "orange_complex_regex" nextgroup=verb
syn match has_pear_tale "pear_complex_regex" nextgroup=verb

syn cluster has_fruity_novel
\ contains=
\    has_apple_poem,
\    has_orange_tale,
\    has_pear_tale


" subject; no 'has' keyword (nor outcome)  "
syn cluster subject
\ contains=
\    @fruity_novel_without_has

" has <fruity_novel>, 'has', and <outcome> "
syn cluster statement 
\ contains=
\    has_fruity_novel

" words  "
syn cluster words
\ contains=
\    @statement,
\    @subject

Am I on the right track?

I'll attempt a short answer here. Based on my experience, it seems you are trying to use classical parsing in a way that is not possible Vim's syntax engine. I would instead "embrace" the faults and make more regex based structures.
Something like this:
syn match fruity_novel "<fruity_novel_regex>" contains=@fruities
syn match outcome "<outcome_regex>" contains=@outcomes contained

syn match statement "<fruity_novel_regex> has <outcome_regex>"
      \ contains=fruity_novel,outcome,hasverb

syn match hasverb "has" contained

syn match apple_poem "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn match orange_tale "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn match pear_fable "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn cluster fruities contains=apple_poem,orange_tale,pear_fable

syn match cheerful_ending "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn match sad_closure "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn match delightful_wrapup "<irrelevant regex>" contained
syn cluster outcomes contains=cheerful_ending,sad_closure,delightful_wrapup

Notice that we here create a match on the entire statement with a large regex. And similarly for the fruity_novel. These regexes must match all the possible variants.
Now, this may not always be possible, in which case things start to become hard - and in some cases, I think we reach a limit where regex based Vim syntax matching does not work.
To be honest, I'm not very experienced with EBNF, and I might have misunderstood how this is supposed to work. However, I believe the core idea I'm presenting is still the right track for you. The point is:

You need a top match that contains what you want.
You need to use the syntax rule order principle: later rules get priority. Thus, in my above version, statement will match if it is a fruity novel followed by "has" and an outcome. If not, the first part will be matched with fruity_novel

Based on your input, I think I am leaving out one important detail, which is that you can match many of these parts that follow each other. But I don't think you really need to use the nextgroup for that, because Vim's syntax matching is "greedy" in the sense that when it was finished matching a statement, it will start "fresh" in the next position. Thus, I believe the "Words" concept may not be so important.
PS! If this is not what you are looking for, then I think it would be much easier to help if you actually provide concrete examples of what we should actually match.

Vim's match (or region) always wants to know both "start" and "end" condition beforehand (though inner matches may extend it afterwards). This is what you're missing in your grammar. If "words" really consume everything until EOF then the grammar could be like this:
syn region fruity_novel start=/ApplePoem/ start=/OrangeTale/ start=/PearFable/ end=/$/ contains=has_statement
syn region has_statement start=/has/ end=/$/ contains=outcome contained
syn match outcome /Cheerful_Ending/ contained
syn match outcome /Sad_Closure/ contained
syn match outcome /Delightful_Wrapup/ contained

It is also possible to make use of "nextgroup" but the result will be somewhat different:
syn match fruity_novel /ApplePoem\|OrangeTale\|PearFable/ nextgroup=has_statement
syn match has_statement /has/ contained nextgroup=outcome
syn match outcome /Cheerful_Ending\|Sad_Closure\|Delightful_Wrapup/ contained

The problem is that fruity_novel may start anytime on topmost level. And so, for example, ApplePoem has OrangeTale will be accepted too (though one may consider this as not a real problem for a syntax highlighter). That is, in order to track "current context" you have to enter into nested region (and therefore to specify its "end" condition beforehand). Otherwise, Vim stays on the current level and may match current item(s) once again.

The use of multiple start=/end= has open a floodgate of additional thought process of seemingly non-binary but intrinsically useful set of additional constructors of vim syntax: need to start studying and exploring that route.  However, the required end= may seem to limit its maximum useability.

Nexting (via region) looks difficult to use when dealing with mostly non-anchoring keywords and even fewer "operator"/"separator" symbols.

I am somewhat cognizant with the fault of vimscript syntax constraint, as I was exploring ways to push my boundaries with simplistic binary questions as see what was mastered out there, and my work (ISC Bind9 and Linux nftables) is a testimony of continual exploration.
